# See all indexes and appropriate columns for table

Tags: postgresql, indexing

How to see all existed indexes for table? for example given table `mytable`, how to see his  every index  with appropriate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'mytable';
```

Answer (score 1):

In `psql` use the `\d` command:

```
postgres=> create table foo (id integer not null primary key, some_data varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> create index foo_data_idx on foo (some_data);
CREATE INDEX
postgres=> \d+ foo
                                  Table "public.foo"
  Column   |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+------------
 id        | integer               | not null  | plain    |              |
 some_data | character varying(20) |           | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "foo_data_idx" btree (some_data)
Has OIDs: no


postgres=>
```

Other SQL tools have other means of displaying this information.